# Set Dynamically Created Autocompete Suggestions Position Under the Entered Field

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

I have Created Dynamically Created Autocomplete. Autocomplete is working Properly.
Problem is the Placing of its suggestion list.

When We Enter In the Autocomplete we get suggestion for it. In my case i have added it to different div. So when I enter into one field  i get suggestion on second field. I have added the picture of it.

As shown in Image when I type into first input i get suggestion on second.

Script:

```
$('body').on('focus',".skill_class", function(){

 $('.skill_class').autocomplete({
    lookup: skill_string,
    appendTo: '.skill_outer_div',
    minChars: 1,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        var selectedValueID = suggestion.data;          
        $(this).closest('.skill_outer_div').find('input[name="key_skill_id_hidden[]"]').val(selectedValueID);
    },  
    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
    noSuggestionNotice: 'No Skill Found.'
});
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group skill_outer_div">        
    <label for="key_skill" class="control-label">Skill *</label>
    <input type="text" name="skill_input[]" id="skill_input" required class="form-control skill_class" />       
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You Must Use id and assign it to all dynamically created components and also not the same change it. Like if div id is **div1**  then after dynamically cread element have new id called **div2**

Comment: In most cases of dynamically created elements,  I prefer id is more reliable then class.

Comment: ok i get that id is more reliable but how do i change all id in dynamically created element?

Comment: See this Link:  https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('focus',".skill_class", function(e){

 $(e.target).autocomplete({
    lookup: skill_string,
    appendTo: '.skill_outer_div',
    ...
```

As there are many fields getting selected by `$('.skill_class')`, jQuery is probably picking and applying the suggestion list to the last item in selection. Using `$(e.target)` instead will help it identify the corresponding field and place the results correctly.